# ggplot2 scale_x_discrete value causing uneven axis spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with rows containing the titles of journal publications, values, and indicating whether it is a `normal` or a `highlight` data point. I want the plot to preserve the order of the data frame. The following code produces an unevenly spaced y-axis.

```
require(ggplot2)

title <- c("COGNITION","MUTAT RES-DNA REPAIR","AM J PHYSIOL-CELL PH","AM J PHYSIOL-CELL PH","BLOOD",
         "PNAS","BIOCHEM BIOPH RES CO","CLIN CANCER RES","BIOCHEM BIOPH RES CO","MOL THER" )
value <- c(-0.428, -0.637, -0.740, -0.782, -0.880, -1.974, -1.988, -2.029, -2.217, -2.242)
indicator <- c(rep("highlight",5), rep("normal",5))

df <- data.frame(title, value, indicator)

mycolors <- c("highlight" = "blue", "normal" = "red")

x_axis_range <- c((min(df$value)), (max(df$value)))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = title, y = value)) +
     geom_point(aes(size=3, color=indicator)) +
     coord_flip() +
     scale_color_manual(values=mycolors) +
     scale_y_continuous(limit=x_axis_range) +

   # produces uneven spacing
     scale_x_discrete(limits=df$title) +

     theme(legend.position="none")

show(p)
```

[image: Uneven y-axis]

I don't know why ggplot is adding extra space between the `MOL THER` and `CLIN CANCER RES` and between the `BLOOD` and `AM J PHYSIOL-CELL PH` data points. When I change the `scale_x_discrete()` line to:

```
   scale_x_discrete(limits=df$title.1) +
```

This spacing becomes even, but the order of the data is changed to alphabetically by title from bottom-to-top.

[image: Even axis but alphabetical]

Why does adding the `.1` to the end of `limits=df$title` even out the spacing? How can I preserve this evenness, and still be able to control the order the data along the y-axis with the `order()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get uneven spacing for the discrete scale because by providing `df$title` you give 10 values but in plot there are only 8 unique values - so there are two spaces for the levels already used.

When you provide `scale_x_discrete(limits=df$title.1)` limits actually are ignored because there is no `title.1` column in your data and result is `NULL`

To get the order you need provide `unique()` values of `df$title` that are converted to character (to keep original order)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = title, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=3, color=indicator)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values=mycolors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limit=x_axis_range) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(as.character(df$title)) )+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Perfect! Great answer.